# Two Controls in the same Column of the WebGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

I have a webGrid with 2 columns and in the first column I have Dates and in Second Column I have one more WebGrid which contains Data according to that Date. Now what I want is I want a Button in the same column in which I have my inner WebGrid.

How can I make that happen..My inner webgrid contains 4 columns in which 2 of them holds DropdownList and other two holds textbox.
I want Button outside this inner WebGrid but inside the Main webGrid.

I hope I am Clear..

Here is My code

```
var grid = new WebGrid(Model, rowsPerPage: 100); 
@if (Model != null)
{

    @grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "EmployeeTasksGrid" },
            tableStyle: "webGrid",
            headerStyle: "header",
            alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
            selectedRowStyle: "select",

columns:
  grid.Columns(
  grid.Column("TaskDate", "Task Date", style: ""),
    grid.Column("EmployeeTask", "Details", format: (resource) =>
    {

        WebGrid resParamGrid = new WebGrid(resource.EmpTasks);
        return resParamGrid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "EmployeeTasksSubGrid" },
            tableStyle: "webGrid subgrid",
    headerStyle: "header",

    selectedRowStyle: "select",

            columns: resParamGrid.Columns(
            resParamGrid.Column("Projects", "Project name",
    format:
        @<div class="taskname selector projects">
            @Html.DropDownList("Projects", null, "--Select--", new { id = "ddl_Projects" })
        </div>, style: "TaskNameWidth"),
     resParamGrid.Column("TaskNames", "Task name",
    format:
        @<div class="taskname selector tasks">
            <input type="hidden" class="hdnActivityId" name="ActivityId" value="@item.ActivityID"/>
            <input type="hidden" class="hdnRecordId" name="RecordID" value="@item.RecordID"/>
            <input type="hidden" class="hdnTaskID" name="TaskName" value="@item.TaskID"/>
            <input type="hidden" class="hdnProjectID" name="ProjectID" value="@item.ProjectID"/>
            <input type="hidden" class="hdnTaskDate" name="TaskDate" value="@item.TaskDate"/>
            <input type="hidden" class="hdnIsFreezed" name="IsFreezed" value="@item.IsFreezed"/>
            @Html.DropDownList("TaskNames", null, "--Select--", new { id = "ddl_Tasks", style = "tasksnew" })
        </div>, style: "TaskNameWidth"),
                       resParamGrid.Column("TaskDescription", "Task Description", format: @<text><textarea
                           rows="3" cols="3" class="taskDiss input">@item.TaskDescription</textarea>
    </text>, style: "col2Width"),
    resParamGrid.Column("Hours", "Hours", format: @<text><input type="text" id="Hours" value="@item.Hours" class="Hours input" onkeypress="javascript:return AllowDecimalNumber(this);"  />
    </text>, style: "col1Width"),
                       resParamGrid.Column("", style: "delete", format: @<text>
    <input type="button" class="delete-task input" />
    </text>, canSort: false)
            ),

            displayHeader: true

        );

   })
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something I would think you could just append the HTML for a button right after the the call to generate the HTML for the second WebGrid.  Something like:

```
return resParamGrid.GetHtml( ... ).ToHtmlString() + @"<input type=""button"" />"
```

You may have to convert the string back to an `IHtmlString` if it is picky about the type.